# How to set Logging Level from getLogger instance

Tags: python, python-logging

python 3.6

How do you set the logging level

I would like to run instantiate a logging class with the following code

```py
import logging
from sys import stdout
from logging import DEBUG, INFO, WARNING, ERROR, CRITICAL, StreamHandler

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logging_level = "DEBUG"
valid_logging_levels = ["DEBUG", "INFO", "WARNING", "ERROR", "CRITICAL"]
if logging_level not in valid_logging_levels:
    raise ValueError(f"Logging level must be one of the following: {valid_logging_levels}")
```

Currently I'm using this syntax to set the logging level, but it's really long

```py
sys_out = StreamHandler(stdout)
if not [isinstance(handler, StreamHandler) for handler in logger.handlers]:
    logger.addHandler(sys_out)
if logging_level == "DEBUG":
    logger.setLevel(DEBUG)
elif logging_level == "INFO":
     logger.setLevel(INFO)
elif logging_level == "WARNING":
    logger.setLevel(WARNING)
elif logging_level == "ERROR":
    logger.setLevel(ERROR)
elif logging_level == "CRITICAL":
    logger.setLevel(CRITICAL)
```

However, that's really long. I thought I could shorten it like the following

```py
log_level = logger.getLevelName(logging_level) 
logger.setLevel(log_level)
```

However, when I run it I get the error message `'Logger' object has no attribute 'getLevelName'` Is there a better way to set a custom logging level?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use `dict` for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
log_levels = {
 'DEBUG': DEBUG,
 'INFO' : INFO,
 'WARNING':WARNING,
 'ERROR': ERROR,
 'CRITICAL':CRITICAL
}
```

and then you can do like this

```
logger.setLevel(log_levels.get(logging_level))
```